# Some functions of js doesn't work since I added fancybox's js files

Tags: javascript, fancybox

As the title of this post says, since I added the fancybox's sources to my file, other js functions doesn't work anymore. If i switch the position of js source files and put mine after fancybox's js source files, my js functions work but the fancybox no, in the other hand, the fancybox work but my js functions don't.

Here is the header of my file:

```
<head>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="imagens/its.png">
<link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- MY CSS -->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- FANCY BOX SOURCES -->

<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>

<!-- FANCY BOX SOURCES -->

<script src="js/myjs.js"></script> <!-- MY JS SOURCE FILE -->
```

I think that src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" is what's doing some conflict..
What can I do ?

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: You're loading two version of jQuery `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js` and `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js`

Comment: yes i know, but if i remove the google's js file, some functions of mine doesn't work, like $("#id").attr("value", ""); for example

Answer (score 0):

You're importing a very old version of jQuery for your own code `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js`, but then importing the latest version for Fancybox `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js`

Many things in the jQuery library have evolved since 1.3 was released almost **5 years ago**, and several old APIs no longer work. The ideal thing to do would be to modernize your own code, and then just import jQuery once (a new or new-ish version).

Start by checking the error console to find out what's breaking.